# Faulty external USB3 enclosure (or is it the cable?)

Tags: usb-storage, usb-3

I have an Orico Toolfree external USB3 2.5" enclosure. Basically toolfree means there are no screws, you just slide the cover open.

It is quite convenient.

And fairly new.

However, once every day or 2 it causes my USB peripherals to temporarily freeze for at least 30 seconds. Maybe 50% of the time this happens, they don't unfreeze and I get an "last USB device malfunctioned error"

And I must reboot if that happens (if they don't unfreeze).

What I'm wondering is what is faulty? Would it likely be the controller in the enclosure? or is there a chance I can rectify the situation with a new USB 3 cable? I don't have an extra one on hand so I'd have to go buy a new one.

To top it off, the other reasonably priced enclosures from other brands also have comments on sites like amazon (similar to the comments on the one I bought), that they are faulty. So it seems like a common thing among enclosures. I don't remember having this problem with my USB 2.0 enclosures though.

Comment: Do you know if the enclosure is UASP capable?  I would recommend that as a bare minimum for these enclosures .  If it isn't, then that may be why it was so affordable.  It seems that you very much get what you pay for with regards to enclosures.  I have a cheap one that is not UASP compliant and it hasn't been especially reliable.

Comment: there is no model # so I can't check for sure, but one being sold on amazon that looks exactly the same from the same manufacturer says that it is UASP capable, so I assume it is.